# Passing jquery variable to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why this isn't working, and it's returning as an object/undefined.

I have a variable outside above the doc.ready:

```
var video_box_original_link = '';
```

I have a link that I click on inside the `ready` function which grabs the info fine:

```
$(document).on('click', '.youtube_video', function(video_box_original_link){
    var my_game_name = $('a.game_title_link').attr('name');
    var my_game_platform = $('a.game_platform_link').attr('name');
    video_box_original_link = "/"+my_game_platform+"/"+my_game_name+"/videos";
});
```

And I have a function that I'm trying to pass to this which is also in the doc.ready down below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popblock_box', function(e, video_box_original_link){
    window.history.pushState("vidPage", "vidPopped", ""+ video_box_original_link +"");
}
```

Is this should be fine?

The "e" is for something else in the script which is not necessary to show.

Comment: Just remove the argument `video_box_original_link` from the `function`.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't pass variable to callback like you do like you do in `function(video_box_original_link)` you should define it in global scope then just use it :

```
var video_box_original_link = '';

$(document).on('click', '.youtube_video', function(){
    var my_game_name = $('a.game_title_link').attr('name');
    var my_game_platform = $('a.game_platform_link').attr('name');

    video_box_original_link = "/"+my_game_platform+"/"+my_game_name+"/videos";
});

$(document).on('click', '.popblock_box', function(e){
    window.history.pushState("vidPage", "vidPopped", ""+ video_box_original_link +"");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, I just had some functions outside of the doc.ready that I wanted to utilize as well. All good.

Comment: You're welcome bro, outside of the doc mean they will loaded before ready function so you could just use them when the DOM is ready check example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/y7tz9t43/).